# Android studio build failing because of dependencies

Tags: android

I get this message Error in Android studio and I don't know why I added card view and recycler and this came threw

if you know something please help me?

[image: my build gradle]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Without a clear description of the error, we cannot help you. Please edit the question to include the textual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably because you have mix version of support library.

Use the same version of all support library. Don't use alpha version, something like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
}
```

And make sure your `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion` is the same version which is `25`.

Comment: thank you for the help i've tried it and it worked just fine (y)